# How to escape <% and %> in java

Tags: java, html, jsp

Hi I am trying to print out `<%` and `%>` using:

```
out.print("<a href=\"same.jsp?item=<%=result.getString(\"College\")%>\">With same name</a>");
```

Basically I am trying to use this in a jsp file using `out.print`:

```
<a href="Search.jsp?item=<%=search%>&item2=<%=value2%>">
```

It is giving me an error when I try to escape `<%` in the jsp file.  Can someone help me how would I escape `<%` and `%>`  in Java.

Comment: @JonnyHenly that was a typo sorry

Comment: Noted, it would still be helpful if you would [edit] your question to include the exact error(s) you're receiving.

Comment: @dnault if that's true then in Java it would be `<\\%`, correct? Since `%` isn't an escapable character in Java.